# Repetir ação a cada segundos #PHP

Tags: php

E criando um projeto e eu precisava que quando o usuário clicasse no botão "INICIAR PONTOS" o Código do `PHP` fosse ativado, a cada 10 segundos ele ganhasse 1 ponto no `database` e isso fosse repetido até que o usuário clicasse no botão "PARAR PONTOS".

Eu já fiz a parte de pontos, mas como faço o do "timer"?

Seria Mais ou Menos Assim:

A cada 10 segundos executa:

```
$sql_soma = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET cpoints = cpoints+1 WHERE users.user_email = '$e_mail'");
```

Comment: E melhor fazer com ajax mano.

Comment: Se a lógica é iniciar a contagem e interromper quando clicar em "PARAR PONTOS",
poderia apenas registrar o momento que iniciou e fazer a soma do tempo e pontos quando interromper. Pouparia requisições e processos diversos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então, você poderia fazer utilizando somente `Javascript`, e posteriormente pegar o valor com `PHP` e salvar no banco de dados. Assim você não precisaria ficar executando querys a cada pouco para atualizar os pontos no banco de dados.

Veja um pequeno exemplo que fiz aqui utilizando o `setInterval` do `Javascript`.

```js
let iniciar = document.getElementById('iniciar');
let finalizar = document.getElementById('finalizar');
let pontuacao = 0;
let contador = 0;
let interval = null;

iniciar.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log('iniciou, espere os 10 segundos.');
  interval = setInterval(contaPontos, 10000);
});

finalizar.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log('parou');
  clearInterval(interval);
});

function contaPontos() {
 contador++;
  document.getElementById("pontos").innerHTML = contador;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="iniciar">Iniciar Jogo</button>
<button type="button" id="finalizar">Finalizar jogo</button>
<p id="pontos"></p>
```